# Any (.NET) Redis SessionStore libraries?

Tags: c#, web-services, redis

I'm trying to search for a good library that uses Redis as a SessionStore for an upcoming WebAPI project. After searching, I've seen this [github repo](https://github.com/angieslist/AL-Redis)  that kind of does that. Any other libraries similar to this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that is based the ServiceStack.Redis client and is available via NuGet:

https://github.com/TheCloudlessSky/Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore

http://nuget.org/packages/Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore